# C# WPF Memory Leak when using Image.source

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting images from multiple cameras and simply put in the Image object in WPF. But there is memory leak problem. Here is the code;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < grabResultsList.Count; i++)
        {


            int width = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Width;
            int height = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Height;
            byte[] pixels = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).PixelData as byte[];
            byte[] pixelsnew = getNewByteArray(pixels, width, height);
            int stride = width / 2 * 3;

            BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width / 2, height / 2, 96d, 96d, pf, null, pixelsnew, stride);

            StackPanel s = MainGrid.Children[i] as StackPanel;
            Image img = s.Children[0] as Image;

            img.Source = bitmap;


            grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

And here is memory graph taken from visual studio; 
[image: CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE]

As you see, RAM graph is increasing continuously.

When I comment this line
                img.Source = bitmap;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < grabResultsList.Count; i++)
        {


            int width = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Width;
            int height = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Height;
            byte[] pixels = grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).PixelData as byte[];
            byte[] pixelsnew = getNewByteArray(pixels, width, height);
            int stride = width / 2 * 3;

            BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width / 2, height / 2, 96d, 96d, pf, null, pixelsnew, stride);

            StackPanel s = MainGrid.Children[i] as StackPanel;
            Image img = s.Children[0] as Image;

            //img.Source = bitmap;


            grabResultsList.ElementAt(i).Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

[image: CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE]

As you see, RAM graph is constant.

I am using GarbageCollector but still I have this problem.
Is there any way to dispose Image object or what should I do?

Comment: I don't see a memory leak. If you use so and so much `Image` objects with bitmaps, then the bitmap data has to be kept in memory. If you don't assign the bitmaps to the images, the bitmaps will eventually be garbage-collected and the memory of the bitmap data released. If you want to get rid of the `Image` objects, remove them from the StackPanel `s`. If you merely want to "reset" them, set their `Source` property back to null.

Comment: @elgonzo I have only 3 Image object. After your comment, I tried to remove existing image object from s stackpanel and created a new Image object and gave new source on that but result is same. when I click preview button, RAM usage is always increasing. I dont understand that when I comment the image.source line, it stands constant. I am stuck :(

Comment: Use the memory profiler, especially the snapshotting and diff function, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/. That being said, there is no need to call GC.Collect manually, as garbage collection is done automatically.

Comment: Have you checked how large the `pixelsnew` arrays are for **each** image? Use the debugger to verify whether any assumptions you have about the data processed by your program are actually correct. Use the profiler (as suggested by ckuri above), to see what is going on in your program memory-wise.

Answer (score 3):

You should freeze the BitmapSource before assigning it to the Image's Source property:

```
bitmap.Freeze();
img.Source = bitmap;
```

---

Besides that, instead of creating a new BitmapSource on each frame, you may reuse a WriteableBitmap:

```
var pw = width / 2;
var ph = height / 2;
var bitmap = img.Source as WriteableBitmap;

if (bitmap == null || bitmap.PixelWidth != pw || bitmap.PixelHeight != ph)
{
    bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pw, ph, 96, 96, pf, null);
    img.Source = bitmap;
}

bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, pw, ph), pixelsnew, stride, 0);
```

Comment: thank you for your interest. But I have solved the problem. It was my fault. I realised that I was always creating new instance of image object.